# Loop through divs backwards — jQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow, dom-traversal

I've made a very simple slideshow. Clicking on the arrow will fade the `$(this)` out, and the next slide will `fadeIn()` using the `next()` function.

However, I cannot seem to reverse this. `prev()` and `next()` don't seem to loop back through the DOM, they just go back up tree. Here is the code and a jsfiddle:

```
$('li').first().siblings().hide();

$('.next').click(function () {
    $(this)
        .parent('body')
        .find('li:first-child')
        .fadeOut(function () {
        $(this)
            .next()
            .fadeIn()
        $(this)
            .appendTo('ul')
    });

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/zYnYM/)

Answer (score 1):

One quick and easy solution is to just use an `active` class to track the current active `li`, which makes your JS a lot simpler. You can simplify it further and put both the click handlers into one function but I left it this way for simplicities sake.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Yqqbv/

```
$('li').first().siblings().hide();
$('li').first().addClass('active');

$('.next').click(function () {
    var $active = $('li.active');

    $active.hide();
    $active.next().fadeIn().addClass('active');
    $active.removeClass('active');
});

$('.back').click(function () {
    var $active = $('li.active');

    $active.hide();
    $active.prev().fadeIn().addClass('active');
    $active.removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: That looks good. However, the `li` do not seem to loop through again. In my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/zYnYM/) they can loop through an infinate amount of times. Could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
$('.back').click(function () {
    $(this)
        .parent('body')
        .find('li:first-child')
        .fadeOut(function () {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .find('li:last-child')
            .fadeIn()
            .prependTo('ul')
    });

});
```

Comment: Tha's great! How come `.find('li:last-child')` and `prependTo()` work?